# Existe algum comando que mostre quantos commit foi feito na branch ?

Tags: git, branch

Eu sempre tive curiosidades nessas coisas, existe algum comando no git que mostre quantos arquivo o dono da branch subiu para o repositório ?

Comment: Sua pergunta me está um pouco confusa para mim. Tente dar um exemplo de coisas que aconteceram no repositório e qual a resposta que você desejaria para que fique mais fácil saber qual seria o comando

Comment: E uma curiosidade boba, exemplo em projetos em equipes onde tem 4 desenvolvedor e cada um deles tem seu branch no repositório, eu gostaria se saber na minha branch quantos arquivos subi para o repositório porque em projetos real você sempre pega as alterações que outro colega subiu para o repositório, por isso essa dúvida é só para saber mesmo se existe algum comando no git que eu possa ver a quantidade de commit

Comment: Respostas devem estar presente na área de respostas, não na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe sim, acredito que o comando que você deseja é o seguinte:

```
git rev-list --count <branch-name>
```

- `rev-list` lista objetos de confirmação em ordem cronológica inversa
- `--count` realiza a contagem desses objetos

Mais informações : [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657295/count-the-number-of-commits-on-a-git-branch)

Fonte: [Documentação git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)

Comment: Eu testei o comando usando minha branch só que ela acabou contando o valor total da master

Comment: Usei esse comando e funfou git shortlog -s -n